# req.isAuthenticated false upon refreshing browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I'm setting up node and currently I am able to login the user but when I refresh the page the login does not persist. My code for logging in the user and checking if a user is currently logged in is below

```
  app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req);
    console.log(req.isAuthenticated()); //upon refresh this is false! Why?
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
      console.log('IT WORKED');
    }
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
  });

  app.post('/api/session', function(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('local-login', function(err, user, info) {
      if (err) { return next(err); }

      req.login(user, function(err) {
        if (err) {
          return res.status(401).json(err);
        } else {
          console.log(req.isAuthenticated()); //this is true so the user is logged in!
          res.send(user.local);
        }
      });

    })(req, res, next);
  });
```

I've spent two days trying to set up auth and I feel like I'm close so any help would be much appreciated, moral is quite low. The documentation for `req.isAuthentiacated` does not exist but every SO or blog post I reference for auth uses it so I feel it's quite common.

Comment: Have you employed the `passport.initialize()` `passport.session()` middleware?

Comment: Yes and I've made sure they are declared in the correct order.

Comment: Hi @Jstuff, I know it was a long time ago, but did you solve? I have the same issue...